# Copy previous row if another row matches its previous row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of order numbers (A) that repeat based on how many items are in the order. The first row of each individual order has a customer tag in col B, but the subsequent rows with the same order number do not. I want a way to copy the previous tags to any matching order number in an array so it can auto-apply. Please see example.

[Playground](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S5yrUOpHdSzVsAmX40luXp4CmjQq-UPfm5j83dGPwcc/edit?usp=sharing)

I've tried the basics of `IF(A2:A=A3:A,B2:B)`, tried to create Queries using multiple columns, `IF(MATCH())`, etc. Tried joining / splitting columns too. Not having much luck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=arrayformula({A2:A,xlookup(A2:A,A:A,B:B,)})
```

[image]

Comment: So simple, yet so effective. Why didn't I think of that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SCAN`

```cpp
=SCAN(,B2:B,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c)))
```